# Python NameError handling - How to catch exception

Tags: python, exception, nameerror

How do you catch a NameError when trying to parse a file into Pandas DataFrame.

**Code Below:**

```
try:
    for filename in os.listdir():
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            df = pd.read_csv(filename)
            break
except NameError:
    print('No SVP file in directory. Please copy from Survey Online directory')
```

If there are no *.txt files in my folder it throws the NameError which I am unable to catch. It cannot file a file, therefore 'df' is not defined.

**Error Below:**

```
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: That `NameError` does not occur in the shown `try` block. Your `try..except` should be around the statement(s) that *use* it.

Comment: where are you using `df` variable? This is the part where you `try catch` should be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you have used does not make a lot of sense. Exception are thrown (and caught) in case something goes wrong with the code. There is nothing that throws an exception in your code. In case there are no `.txt` files, you will just never define `df`. A different thing would be if you tried to access `df` and it didn't exist. For example, try this:

```py
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        break

try:
    df.head()
except NameError:
    print('No SVP file in directory. Please copy from Survey Online directory')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
import os

import pandas as pd

try:
    for filename in os.listdir():
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            df = pd.read_csv(filename)
            break
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Some error occured -  {err} ')

# write try catch block when you are trying to access the `df` variable when it could be non-existent.
try:
    print(df)
except NameError:
    print('No SVP file in directory. Please copy from Survey Online directory')
```

**Output :**

```
No SVP file in directory. Please copy from Survey Online directory
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern for this. I personally prefer it to catching an exception later because its very clear what the code is doing.

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        break
else:
    # your error code here
```